# How to make sure a php script keeps running on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, laravel, process, watchdog

For my Linux servers, I use [this](https://gist.github.com/mauris/11375869) script to make sure my queue listeners keep running in the background. I tried to get it working on Windows, but without luck so far. I need to get the PID of the started php process, but I can't find a way to do this in Windows.

How can I get the PID of a process started with `exec()` on Windows, or, how can I make sure my Laravel queue listeners keep running on Windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129439/how-to-find-out-a-specific-process-is-still-running-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways for getting the pid. First oft all you can use the taskmanager or the terminal and the tasklist command.

You can also use the exec() to execute the tasklist command and get the pid.

Last but not least, you could use the phpfunction getmypid().
http://php.net/manual/de/function.getmypid.php

Answer (score 0):

You could also use https://eyewitness.io to monitor your queues and cron jobs. You'll get an alert if any of them stop working. There is a Laravel 4 package available to help make integration easier.